# Why we use pointer to integer for max stl function instead for size_t data type(which is generally use) for array of characters in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, stl, size-t

I was working on a problem and need to find the maximum character (alphabetically or we can say according to ASCII values) and found that size_t data type can't be use for returning from the max function defined in algorithm header file instead I found pointer to integer for that .

below is the piece of code I am having doubt:

int v[] = { 'a', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h' };

```
int* i1; 

i1 = std::max_element(v, v + 4);
```

Can anyone explain me why? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `max_element` returns an iterator to an element of the range given, not an index.  In the case of an array, those iterators are pointers.

Comment: don't try to find out how c++ works by guessing, instead consult some reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because std::max_element is not only a function for arrays. It is a function that works with any iterator. And indexes are meaningful only for random access containers, so using an index as return value would unnecessarily limit the interface of the algorithm.